# c++ WinApi : GetClientRect fails

Tags: c++, winapi, screensaver

I am coding a screensaver program running on Windows.

In preview mode, Windows calls the program this way :
`Screensaver.exe /p ParentWindowHandle`

However, when I make this call in my program :
`BOOL res = GetClientRect(parentWindowHandle, rect)`
res is FALSE, rect is NULL and I get `ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE` with `GetLastError()`

`GetWindowRect` gives me the same results.

But, if I make a call to `BOOL res = IsWindow(parentWindowHandle)` instead, I get res == TRUE. Does this not mean I have a valid window handle ?

The code looks like this :

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    unsigned int handle = GetHandleFromCommandLine(pCmdLine); // Custom function (tested and approved :) )
    HWND parentWindowHandle = (HWND) handle;
    LPRECT rect = NULL;
    BOOL res = GetClientRect(parentWindowHandle, rect);
    // here, rect == NULL, res == FALSE and GetLastError() returns ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE

    // ...
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Your problem discusses `parentWindowHandle`, while your code has `parentWindow`.  Is the code in the example exactly what you have that is failing?  What is the `GetHandleFromCommandLine` function doing?

Comment: You should be using these functions by making an object (`RECT r;`) and passing the address (`&r`), rather than a pointer that doesn't even have an object.

Comment: @Chad Sorry, I corrected it. GetHandleFromCommandLine is parsing the command line to get the handle to the parent window. I tested this one, it should work.

Comment: @chris : I just tried to make a rect and pass it as a pointer, but I get the same results. Thanks for the tip anyway :)

Comment: @Jack, Yes, the pointer here is NULL, so it wouldn't matter, but if you use a pointer itself to pass in, you need to allocate an object for it first via `LPRECT r = new RECT; GetClientRect(hwnd, r);` Not dealing with pointers at all is much easier, though.

Comment: @chris : That's right, and yes, I will take the non-pointer way, I think :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On 64-bit Windows, a window handle is 64 bits and cannot fit in an `unsigned int`, so your cast is producing a value that is an invalid window handle.  You should modify your `GetHandleFromCommandLine` function so that it returns a proper `HWND`, not an `unsigned int`, and no type cast is necessary.

Also, `GetClientRect` returns the rectangle by storing it into the value pointed at by the second parameter.  If you pass it `NULL`, it has nowhere to store that, so it will either crash or fail with an invalid parameter error.  To avoid that, pass in the address of a local variable:

```
RECT rect;
GetClientRect(..., &rect);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response :)
It might indeed come from the cast : If I have the good handle in a std::string, how should I cast it to a HWND ?

Comment: Yes, it was indeed a cast problem. If I switch the unsigned int to unsigned long, I get a valid HWND. Thanks !

Comment: While the HWND type is indeed 64-bits on Win64, the actual values fit fine into 32-bit data types: in fact this is required so that 32 and 64 bit apps can communicate via windows messages. If you want to see this for yourself, start the 64-bit version of Spy++, and you'll see it only displays 32-bits worth of data for the HWNDs. Also, on Win64, int and long are the same size: 32bits; changing the cast from int to long should make no difference. (If you do want a datatype that matches the pointer size, use INT_PTR or one of the other _PTR suffix types.) The real problem here is likely the RECT.